# app.config in asp.net core 1.0 rc2 class library

Tags: asp.net-core, class-library

Is it possible to read custom sections defined in the app.config in a .net core 1.0 class library project? In the asp.net core web project the custom sections are read correctly from the config however they are not accessible when called from a class library project. Prior to the upgrade and in a rc1 class library proj the app.config sections were being read however that is not the case after the upgrade.

Is there a setting in the project.json that I am missing or do I need to create a custom configuration provider?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What is the content of your app.config file?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin - the app.config file has app settings, connection strings and other custom configuration settings (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). The .net core class lib proj has reference to another .net core class lib proj which in turn has reference to a nuget pkg containing older .net class libraries built in 2.0/4/0 fwk and these libraries need the app config to drive the configuration functionality.